# How to add progress bar on customtkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, progress-bar, tqdm, customtkinter

```
import customtkinter as CTK

class App(CTK.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    self.bar = CTK.CTkProgressBar(master=self.checkbox, orientation='horizontal', mode='determinate')
    self.bar.grid(row=10, column=0, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="n")


    def test(self):
    for x in range(500):
        return x**2
```

I want so that when I want I run the test function (via a button I already have made which works fine by itself) the bar starts and when it ends it stops. Although best would be if there was a way to use tqdm progress bar in the UI itself in place of the tkinter one?

I've tried adding self.bar.start() and stop at start/end of the function but doesn't seem to work. It only runs after the function itself is done.

Comment: Post what you have tried on using `self.bar.start()`.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from starting and stopping the progress bar, you need to update it on each iteration. The [documentation](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/wiki/CTkProgressBar) states that the bar goes from 0 to 1, so you will need to come up with a way to measure your increments and then re-scale them to a float between the required range.

You will also need to set an initial value for the progress bar immediately after your widget declaration, since the default is 0.5 (half-way).

Additionally, you will need to use the `update_idletasks()` method for the progress bar to actually move on each step. Otherwise, it will wait until the task is executed and then update the values.

```
import customtkinter as CTK

class App(CTK.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    self.bar = CTK.CTkProgressBar(master=self.checkbox,
                                  orientation='horizontal',
                                  mode='determinate')
    
    self.bar.grid(row=10, column=0, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="n")
    
    # Set default starting point to 0
    self.bar.set(0)
    
    def test(self):
        n = 500
        iter_step = 1/n
        progress_step = iter_step
        self.bar.start()
        
        for x in range(500):
            self.bar.set(progress_step)
            progress_step += iter_step
            self.update_idletasks()
        self.bar.stop()
```

Now you just need to include a button or some other object to initialize your function.

Regarding the return statement, I would not recommend doing it that way. You could alternatively append each element to a list and return it upon progress bar conclusion.

Hope this helps.