# How to stop a thread getting stuck in Tkinters mainloop?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I'm somewhat new to python, so sorry if I haven't done thinks in a nominal way.
I have a thread called 'thread1' that loops increasing the 'num' variable by 1 as quickly as it can. Every time it increases 'num' it then sets the widget in my Application using the 'update_widget' function located in my 'App' class. The Problem is that when I call 'cleanup' the thread gets stuck and never calls its 'end_thread' script like it should. This means that my app is waiting for this to happen and so it freezes.
Below is a simplified version of my project in one script. This script recreates the problem I was having.

```
# test7.py

import tkinter as tk
import threading
from time import sleep


class Thread1:
    def __init__(self, a, d):
        self.app = a
        self.data = d

        self.ended = False

    def end_thread(self):
        print("Ending Thread")
        self.ended = True
        raise SystemExit

    def loop(self):
        print("Initialize Loop")
        num = 0
        while True:
            if self.data.end: self.end_thread()
            num += 1
            self.app.update_widget(str(num))


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, d):
        super().__init__()
        self.data = d

        self.widget = tk.Entry(self)
        self.widget.pack()

    def update_widget(self, text):
        print("Updating Widget")
        self.widget.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.widget.insert(0, text)


class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        self.end = False


def cleanup():
    print("Closing")
    data.end = True
    while not thread1_class.ended:
        sleep(0.2)
    else:
        raise SystemExit


print("Name: ", __name__)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = Data()
    app = App(data)
    thread1_class = Thread1(app, data)

    thread1 = threading.Thread(target=thread1_class.loop)
    thread1.start()

    app.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", cleanup)
    app.mainloop()
```

Things I have tried include:

- Removing the widget before enabling the 'data.end'.
- Adding a variable to Stop updating before enabling the 'data.end'.
- Running the 'cleanup' in another thread.
- Creating a thread inside the 'App' class that will check for data changes.

I have realised from my testing that the reason the thread gets stuck is because the main thread isn't available for it to update the widgets because it's in a while loop waiting for the sub thread to end. I don't know how to get around this.

Comment: You shouldn't have a thread calling methods on `tkinter` widgets. `Tkinter` is not thread-safe.

Comment: Hi @quamrana, what would you suggest as a method of updating tkinter widgets from ever changing data? I am going to try creating a thread inside the 'App' class that will check for data changes.

Comment: I've been told that calling `event_generate` is safe to call from other threads. You can use that to send a signal to the tkinter thread that it needs to do some work.

Comment: You can use a thread-safe queue (`queue.Queue` I believe) to pass data or perhaps lambdas to, say, a function which uses `tk.after()` to repeatedly have itself called, servicing the queue.

Comment: @BryanOakley It's possible to crash `tkinter` if there's a `tkinter` object referenced in a thread. For example [this](https://pastebin.com/wF5Fn19a) mre that crashes python just because a `tkinter` object is accessible from a thread other than the one where the `tk.Tk()` is created. If you have any comments on it, feel free to start a new chat so that we can discuss it.

Comment: @TheLizzard: I don't argue that using threads is problematic. However, your example doesn't show that using `event.generate` will cause an error. I can modify your example to call `event.generate` and it doesn't cause the app to crash.

Comment: @TheLizzard: accessing root via a global worked for me using your example as a starting point.

Comment: Upon the suggestions of the people here, I found that this only freezes 1 in around 4 times. It freezes when the Thread is doing 'self.app.event_generate("<<Update>>", when='tail')' and the main loop is in the 'while' loop for cleanup.

num += 1

self.data.num = num

if self.data.end is False: self.app.event_generate("<<Update>>", when='tail')

Comment: perhaps you're looking for something like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77295917/customtkinter-progress-bar-with-a-stoppable-thread/77296110#77296110